# Campagnolo master link won't fit

Tags: chain, master-link

I bought a Campagnolo master link ([this one](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/200891575113?ssPageName=STRK%3aMEWNX%3aIT&_trksid=p3984.m1497.l2649)) for use with my Campy 10 speed chain. When it's not on a chain, it joins up and clicks into place and all is well.

However, when I try to fit it around the chain link the pin doesn't seem to go through far enough to allow the groove in the pin to 'engage' with the opposite groove. Based on the packet it seems there are different pin lengths.

How do I know what pin length I should aim to get to fit my chain? Are there different 'standard' lengths for Campy chains?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Campagnolo have 2 types of 10 speed chain, 6.2mm and 5.88mm (Ultra Narrow).

If you have the older C10 chain you will need a 6.2mm master link.

Measure the chain to confirm the width but this is likely the issue.

Comment: Thanks! I'll measure tonight. Why are bike parts so hard to get right??